# Nested Query in From and Having clauses

Tags: python, sql

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
company_name varchar(200),
market varchar(200),
funding_total integer,
status varchar(20),
country varchar(10),
state varchar(10),
city varchar(30),
funding_rounds integer,
founded_at date,
first_funding_at date,
last_funding_at date,
PRIMARY KEY (company_name,market,city)
);
```

Query:

What is/are the state(s) that has/have the largest number(s) of startups  in the "Security" market (i.e. market column contains the word "Security"), listing all ties?

Code:

```
db.executescript("""
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS q3;

    select companies.state, count(*)as total
    from companies
    where companies.market like '%Security%'
    group by companies.state
    having count(*) = 
    (
    select max(countGroup) as maxNumber
    from (select C.state, count(*) as countGroup
        from companies as C
        where C.market like '%Security%'
        group by C.state)
     );

"""
```

EDIT:
There is still an error because the output/result is empty. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try adding space there ->> count(*) AS TOTAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. (Please adapt syntax of your RDBMS)

```
select state, total from 
(    select companies.state, count(*)as total
from companies
where companies.market like '%Security%'
group by companies.state
) as countgroups
where total =
(
select max(countGroup) as maxNumber
from (select C.state, count(*) as countGroup
    from companies as C
    where C.market like '%Security%'
    group by C.state)
 );
```

Alternatively:

```
select state, total from
(select companies.state, count(*)as total
from companies
where companies.market like '%Security%'
group by companies.state
) order by 2 desc
limit 1; --please adapt syntax of your RDBMS
```

Comment: Did that yield the expected results?

Comment: Yes! And you know what my problem was? I forgot to say "create view q3 as" at the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

Surround the subquery with parentheses

Comment: Thanks. After I added a pair of parentheses, the syntax error is gone, but my query result/output is still empty.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter unintentionally. I've added a new answer.